# 'PushmoteSDK/Headers/Pushmote.h' file not found when trying to use pushmote sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I am trying to follow the steps given here:

http://docs.pushmote.com/docs/import-pushmote-ios-sdk-swift

but I am getting this error: 'PushmoteSDK/Headers/Pushmote.h' file not found, when I try and build my app.

Its my Pushmote-Bridging-Header.h file that has this import statement and the file is clearly there, in project_dir/PushmoteSDK.framework/Headers/Pushmote.h

I have read about a few other header file not found error with xcode and the solutions seem to vary a lot, so I think it might have to do with the specific version of xcode. Perhaps someone has used pushmote with xcode7 before and can assist?

EDIT:

This is my Pushmote-Bridging-Header.h file found in /Users/alex/ios_projects/Monkey/Monkey/Pushmote-Bridging-Header.h

```
#ifndef Pushmote_Bridging_Header_h  
#define Pushmote_Bridging_Header_h
#import "PushmoteSDK/Pushmote.h"
#endif /* Pushmote_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change import line like this;

```
#import "PushmoteSDK/Headers/Pushmote.h"
```

to

```
#import "PushmoteSDK/Pushmote.h"
```

Comment: does the Pushmote-Bridging-Header go in the project directory or the target project name directory?

Comment: It should be in the same directory with AppDelegate.swift.

Comment: I am still experiencing the same issue. I have updated the question to clarify what the current code is